# Strange: WinForms form closes automatically after button press

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My app is WinForms .NET 4 (C#) and one of the forms keeps on closing automatically after pressing a button.

- The form DOES have default Accept and Cancel buttons but these are not touched.
- There is a ButtonTestConnection_Click event which when clicked, does its job but closes the form somehow.
- I am using the mouse to click the button so this is NOT a case of cascading keystrokes.
- I am NOT setting the DialogResult in this function.

I also tried to check for stray this.Close / this.Dispose calls but found none.

Here is the code:

```
private void ButtonTestConnection_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Enabled = false;
    this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;

    this.ProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
    this.ProgressBar.Maximum = 500;
    this.ProgressBar.Value = 0;

    this.ProgressBar.Visible = true;
    this.ButtonTestConnection.Visible = false;

    try
    {
        while (this.ProgressBar.Value < this.ProgressBar.Maximum)
        {
            // Some proxy code.
            this.ProgressBar.Value++;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    this.ProgressBar.Visible = false;
    this.ButtonTestConnection.Visible = true;

    this.ProgressBar.Invalidate();
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

    this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
    this.Enabled = true;

    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling it may have something to do with setting the button to not enabled whch probably shifts the focus. Not sure yet.

Comment: Take everything out of the event handler and then start adding one line at a time to find out which line causes the problem (optimize using binary search)

Comment: Override the form's OnFormClosing method.  Set a breakpoint on it and look at the call stack when it hits.  Post it in your question if you can't make sense of it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Steve's answer below turned out to be the case.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check if the property `DialogResult` on the button equals to `None`.
If not, then the form will be closed when you hit that button and the form will return the setting of the Button's DialogResult property.

Usually, this happens a lot when you copy/paste an existing form's button but forget to remove on the pasted button the original DialogResult setting

Comment: To prove this I would detach the button from the event and click it. I bet the same results will happen.

Comment: Thank you. It was a copy-paste issue after all. I never noticed the DialogResult accessible through the designer before since people generally set it through code.

Comment: Still happens in .net 4.7.1. In my case I don't think I ever set the property directly in the designer (didn't realize it was there) but I did do an "add existing" on a dialog and some copy pasting so I had two buttons acting like this